# Adjusting toolbar height for material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The blue marked area takes up a lot of space. How can I adjust the height of the Toolbar?
Can you show by example?

Or how can I create a css file and import it into the toolbar. I need to change the height, I couldn't change whatever I did. please can you help with this?

There is almost no method I have not tried.
In short, I want to adjust the height of the Mtabletoolbar field marked in blue.

[image]

```
 <MaterialTable
 Toolbar: props => (
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', }}>
            <MTableToolbar {...props} classes={{ customizeToolbar: "15px" }} />
          </div>
        ),
 />
```

`

```
  const styles = {
    customizeToolbar: {
      minHeight: "100px"
    }
  }
```

`

I have been trying for 2 days, please can you help with the subject?
I need to change the style structure below. especially I have to change the min-height

```
 .MuiToolbar-regular {
    min-height: 64px;
 }
```

`

```
  .MuiToolbar-root {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .MuiToolbar-regular {
    min-height: 56px;
  }
   @media (min-width:0px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .MuiToolbar-regular {
      min-height: 48px;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width:600px) {
     .MuiToolbar-regular {
      min-height: 64px;
    }
   }
  .MuiToolbar-dense {
    min-height: 48px;
  }
```

`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-nash-2s5ff

Comment: Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Simply adjust the style of the element where `blue` appears,

and make the child vertical center as below:

```html
<div
  style={{
    backgroundColor: "lightblue",
    height: "200px",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center"
  }}
>
  <MTableToolbar {...props} />
</div>
```

[image]

[image: Edit stoic-https-e8q4d]

Comment: your solution is very nice,
but
backgroundColor: "lightblue", height: '15px'
{... props} style = {{height: '100%'}}

As I set it as the article does not appear, I want to ensure that it is appropriate for the scale in the literature.